# Массивы в ассемблерной вставке

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, ассемблер

Необходимо объявить целочисленный массив размера n на c++, а инициализировать его уже в ассемблерной вставке числами от одного до n. Написал следующий код, но он выдает ошибку:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
  {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter integer value: ";
    cin >> n;

    int* p_darr = new int[n];

    __asm
    {
        mov ecx, n
        mov esi, 0
        GO:
        mov p_darr[esi], esi
            inc esi
            loop GO
    }

    delete[] p_darr;
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка прикреплена скриноштом: [image: Ошибка]

Скажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить

Comment: Почему он бесконечный? В регистре ecx находится значение n. Loop GO с каждым проходом цикла уменьшает значение регистра ecx на 1 до тех пор, пока ecx не будет равен 0. Далее просиходит выход из цикла. Разве я неправ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ассемблерных вставках имя переменной обозначает её адрес, а не значение. Поэтому `p_darr` - это адрес самого указателя, а не массива, на который он указывает. Так что сначала нужно извлечь значение этого указателя (адрес массива), прочитав его в регистр, и с этим значением уже работать дальше:

```
    mov ecx, n
    mov esi, 0
    mov eax, p_darr
GO:
    mov [4*esi+eax], esi
    inc esi
    loop GO
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы мне очень помогли